# Проблема установки python библиотеки на сервер (Heroku)

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku

Есть бот написанный на python(3.6.10) в нем есть функции для трансляции музыки в голосовой чат. Функция реализованная на модуле `FFmpegPCMAudio` из `discord.py`.

После деплоя бот работает и все хорошо, но при вызове команды музыки, в консоль выдает ошибку:

```
ERROR: ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found. Please install one.
```

Вот мой файл `requirements.txt`:

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py.git
git+https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl.git
ffmpeg==1.4
requests==2.23.0
```

Подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: P.s локально все работает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить модули:

```
pip3 install ffprobe
pip3 install avprobe
```

Или

```
pip3 install ffmpeg
pip3 install avconv
```